# Get information from another method in the same class C# Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

BI pretty new to C# and Im really confused how to get information from a method, and then use it in another method in the same class..

So far I got this script

```
public class DragDropBehaviour : MonoBehaviour 
{
private Vector3 screenPoint;
private Vector3 offset;

void OnMouseDown()
    {
        screenPoint = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(gameObject.transform.position);
        offset = gameObject.transform.position - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenPoint.z));
        Debug.Log("Clicked "+gameObject.name);
    }

public void OnMouseDrag()
    {
        Vector3 curScreenPoint = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenPoint.z);
        Vector3 curPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(curScreenPoint)+offset;
            transform.position = curPosition;
            var objectPosition = curPosition;
        }
}
```

After the event and my with OnMouseDrag I want to do something like this:

```
void OnMouseUp()
        {
            Debug.Log("GameObject is now at "+onMouseDrag.objectPosition);  
        }
```

But I can't seem to understand how to get out the information from the curPosition in my OnMouseDrag.

How can I solve this in a simple and easy way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move the `objectPosition` variable, so it's a class instance instead of a method instance.

```
public class DragDropBehaviour : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private Vector3 screenPoint;
    private Vector3 offset;

    private Vector3 ObjectPosition;
```

Now the `OnMouseDrag()` event can assign to it, and the `OnMouseUp` event can read from it.

```
public void OnMouseDrag()
{
    Vector3 curPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(curScreenPoint)+offset;
    ...
    ObjectPosition = curPosition;
}

void OnMouseUp()
{
    Debug.Log(string.Concat("GameObject is now at ", ObjectPosition));
}
```

Normally, if you wanted to return a value then your method would have a return type, but events don't have return types.

Comment: So I move it to outside the method, and then access it by using Debug.Log("GameObject is now at "+DragDropBehaviour.ObjectPosition); ?

Comment: Thanks. And later if I want to access the same information from another class, Ill be able to use DragDropBehaviour.ObjectPosition to access it?